# Merging two Images (imageOne from Drawables & imageTwo from camera)

Tags: android, image, merge, camera

I am developing an app which uses surface.callback to initialize the front camera when the app is started. I have done overlayering on the camera and added some buttons along with some funny images.

Now there are three ways to do this as far as my knowledge goes (and I am a newbie so if there's another method that would also be appreciable.)

- Capture image: The problem is that if I capture the image from
  camera, I won't get the funny images which are added on the top of
  the camera preview.
- Screenshot: As I have done this through overlayering, hence taking a 
  screenshot through code of a selected portion isn't yielding any 
  result also. Because it only takes the screenshot of the layer with
  buttons and funny image but not the screenshot of the camera preview 
  as it is behind the layout containing above mentioned items.
- Now the only resort is that I merge two images. One from my drawables
  folder (funny images) and second obtained at runtime from front
  camera.

Anyone who can kindly help me merge two images. I have seen some tutorials/codes but they take both images from drawables folder while my second image is obtained at runtime through camera.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the camera image and edit it (overlay with funny images) before writing it to file.